# Lost trying to figure out the correct query

Tags: mongodb

Select all the different and last(by saved_date) ticker('t') of the day and order(desc) them by cp_fix value.

This is a record:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53149f620c2c3735567a3272"),
    "c" : "-1.03",
    "ccol" : "chr",
    "e" : "NASDAQ",
    "ltt" : "10:27AM EST",
    "cp_fix" : "-1.61",
    "c_fix" : "-1.03",
    "l" : "63.05",
    "s" : "0",
    "lt" : "Mar 3, 10:27AM EST",
    "t" : "ABCO",
    "l_fix" : "63.05",
    "cp" : "-1.61",
    "id" : "667046",
    "saved_date" : ISODate("2014-03-03T19:55:53.454Z"),
    "l_cur" : "63.05"
}
```

I don't know even where to begin because I think the 'distinct' clause should be used, but it seems it can't be combined with the other clauses. I thought about the aggregation operations but I don't see nothing that needs to be aggregated.

Edit: I've been reading some similar questions on SO and Google and I've got the following query:

```
var yesterday = new Date();
var today = new Date();
yesterday.setDate(today.getDate() -1)

db.stock_history.aggregate([
    {$sort: {"saved_date": -1}},
    {$project: {"t":1 }},
    {$group: {"_id": "$t"}},
    {{$match: { saved_date: { $gte: yesterday, $lt: today}}}
    {$limit:20}
])
```

I don't really know if the query is correct, because I get the following error when I try to run it:

```
Error: Printing Stack Trace
    at printStackTrace (src/mongo/shell/utils.js:37:7)
    at DBCollection.aggregate (src/mongo/shell/collection.js:897:1)
    at (shell):1:18
Sat Mar  8 20:05:39.102 JavaScript execution failed: aggregate failed: {
    "errmsg" : "exception: terminating request:  request heap use exceeded 10% of physical RAM",
    "code" : 15944,
    "ok" : 0
} at src/mongo/shell/collection.js:L898
```

Comment: What do you mean by distinct and also last? I would assume that the last of the day clause would give you distinct anyway.

Comment: There are several records with the same ticker in the same day.

Comment: The aggregation framework is definitely what you want to use here.  Read up on that and update your answer with what you ended up trying if you're not able to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks, @JohnnyHK. I edited the original post with the information.

Answer (score 0):

You clearly have a large dataset and are running into memory problems, but there are some other reasons for the problem. See the query:

```js
db.stock_history.aggregate([
    {"$match": { "saved_date": { "$gte": yesterday, "$lt": today }}}
    {"$sort": { "t": 1, "saved_date": 1 }},
    {"$group": {
         "_id": "$t",
         "cp_fix": {"$last": "$cp_fix"}
         "saved_date": {"$last": "$saved_date"}
    }},
    {"$sort": {"cp_fix": -1}},
    {"$limit":20}
])
```

- With large data the first thing you want to do is $match. This will reduce what is going through the other pipeline stages, and is also your only opportunity to use an index for selection. Think of this as doing a `.find()` before doing any other work.
- Sort the result by "t" and "saved_date" so they are in order
- Grouping. Distinct values of "t" and the **last** values at that boundary
- Sort finally by the "cp_fix" value

You memory issue is likely because you needed to reduce the set with the **$match** first.

Is this a homework question from https://education.mongodb.com/ ? Because it looks kind of familiar.